# The hint attribute dose not work for the password in an editetext

Tags: android

The hint attribute dose not work for the password in an `editetext`. Even when I set the `hint` text for the password field, when I see it in my device, I can not see the `hint` text on the password filed.

Comment: Could you add code of your xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```